# Ошибка с index.css и favicon в React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, proxy

Я разрабатываю клиент-серверное приложение на React и Express. Сервер React у меня запускается на 3000 порту, а сервер express, на 5000. Для отправки запросов я использую proxy (инфу брал вот из этой статьи [react-express](https://tuhub.ru/posts/react-express)). Всё отрабатывает нормально, с сервера приходит результат, но после того, как я добавил proxy в package.json ("proxy": "http://localhost:5000") в консоли стали появляться вот такие ошибки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В IDE также появляется консольная ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом приложение продолжает работать нормально, стили, которые прописаны в index.css вроде применяются. В выше указанной статье говорится, что каждый раз когда ваше React приложение делает запрос не за статическим ресурсом (не за изображением, CSS или index.html), он будет перенаправлять запрос на сервер указанный в "proxy". Хоть проблема ни как и не отражается на работе приложения - она есть. Как можно это исправить?